# Add keys to array elements

Tags: php, arrays, key

Let's say I have an array looking like this:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Now I want to add the key "id" to each element in the above array to make the array structure look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1,
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2,
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3,
    )  
)
```

I can't figure out how to solve this, does anyone know?

Comment: Well you cannot do it like that as you would have 3 keys in an array all the same (duplicates). That aint legal or possible

Comment: That will not do. Array keys must be unique.

Comment: Anyway, if they are all `id`'s what would be the point. Just call the array a better name like `$id_array`

Comment: A duplicate key is not possible. Instead, you can use this code ```<?php

$array = [1, 2, 3];

$array2=array();

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    $array2[]=array("id"=>$value);
}

print_r($array2); 
?>``` 

if you want to use the same key value but under a different array key.

Comment: The best you can get in this case is an array like this `$array = ['id' => [1, 2, 3]]`. As has been pointed out you cannot use duplicate keys in an array. Assigning values to the same key will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: @MohamedAzharuddin That was actually the answer I was looking for so thanks a lot! :-D (I've updated my question for clarification.)

Comment: @eqinna I have posted my answer, if that answers your question you can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the reference of the [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). A duplicate key is not possible in the array. Instead, you can use the below code. if you want to use the same key but under a different array key.

```
<?php  

$array = [1, 2, 3];  

$array2=array(); 
 
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{     
$array2[]=array("id"=>$value); 
}  

print_r($array2);  ?>
```

The output will look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to obtain your disered array with the same key value but under a different array key :

```
<?php

$array = [1, 2, 3]; 
$newarray=array(); 

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    
    $newarray[]=array("id"=>$value); 

} 

print_r($newarray);
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```